# Cloud Function & OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I have a issue to use OAuth2.0 on GCP Cloud Function. I use to run this code locally. it works and it open a web browser's page to ask access to my gmail account.
I know that `InstalledAppFlow` is only use for local application.

```
    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("credentials.json", SCOPES) # <-- Oauth2.0 credential 
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

I then tried to do another way using /tmp repesitory to store the token but still doesn't work and I can't see where is the issue ... Do you have any idea ? thank you so much

```
    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json' #OAuth credentials
    APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python'

    def get_credentials():

        store = oauth2client.file.Storage("/tmp/tempcredentials.json")
        credentials = store.get()
        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
            flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
        return credentials
```

Comment: Do you have error logs?

Comment: I only get the status "crash" in the logs but not enough information to know whats going wrong...

Comment: Both code work locally for you?

Comment: There's currently a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/155215191) about missing traces when CF fails with python37. You should check the description in there and see if it's your case. If so, apply the workaround of manually catching and logging the exception and share the error message here.

Comment: Yes sorry @guillaumeblaquiere , both code are working locally thats why i'm getting confused..

Comment: Did you try to add `print()` on each line to see what crash exactly? Did you try to replace the `get()` with `locked_get()`? Do you know that oauth2client library is deprecated for a while now?

Comment: Locally nothing crashed. Print() doesn't appear in logs, at least not for cloud function . thank you i'll maybe try to use locked_get() i didn't try it yet. Thanks now I know its deprecated but it shouldn't be a problem, I know the package won't be updated and security breach won't be fix.. but it should still be working. Anyway thank u for your answer, i'll explore google-auth

Comment: Did you try the workaround I provided in order to log the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files) the temporary folder is just for creating temporary files that will be stored in RAM memory and only available for the instance currently executing your code, thus there's no guarantee of persistence between invocations.

You should check [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail) as it explains how to authenticate from Cloud Functions into Gmail (you will need more than a single function).